# Fragment is recreated between tabs

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have three fragments, lets say Fragment A, B and C. Those are in a sliding tabs layout.

**Illustration here** : http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2015/27/1435684108-fdsf.png

When i open the application, i'm on fragment A and i do a volley request in it.
The list view on fragment A is populated by data that i get from volley response.
No problems so far.

When i switch from fragment A to fragment B, and then go back to fragment A, nothing change : the list view is still populated and fragment is not recreated ( normal situation ).

The problem is when i switch from fragment A to fragment C, and then go back to fragment A : It seems like fragment A is recreated ( i have my blank screen with the loading spinner until volley request gives a response and populates the list view, like when i launch the application )

I can switch by clicking on each tab name or by a sliding gesture, the problem is still the same.

**So my question is** : Why is fragment A recreated when i switch from A to C and then go back to A, but is not recreated when i switch from A to B and go back to A.

Thank you people and sorry for bad english.

Comment: You need to show your code.

Comment: How do you change your Fragments? Post the relevant code

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this code

```
 mCustomViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
```

Which means the three fragment will be in the stack, and no need to recreate them.